# how to make paragraph center

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make paragraph center

I am using card

I am trying margin-left and margin-right and padding-left and padding-right but not work properly

I am trying to make paragraph one line below the service

```
<div class="card" style="width: 70rem;margin-top:120px;margin-left:120px;">
    <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column">

        <div class="row">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="~/Graphics/homeiconservicepage.svg" style="width:25px;height:25px;" />
            <a href="@ViewBag.link">@ViewBag.text</a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="justify-content-center d-flex">
            <span> <text font-size:50px;"> @ViewBag.text </text></span>

        </div>

        <div class="justify-content-center d-flex" >
            <p>
                We enable organizations from startups to large enterprises
                to make their work environment more efficient.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1552519507-da3b142c6e3d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" style="width:1200px;height:400px;" alt="Card image">
</div>
```

Current Output

[image]

Comment: Use the class ``text-center`` to align item centre

Comment: @OMiShah when I try your suggestion then not work see this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMH4F.png can you help more

Comment: @OMiShah I am using card

Comment: Please update your code so that we can get the same results. Makes it easier for us to help :D

Comment: @AudunHilden this is my updated code I am trying to another person suggestion but not work

Comment: Update your code so that we can get the same results as the picture you posted above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am on phone so I cannot use the snippet (Codepen: https://codepen.io/Maxigui/pen/NWrxwRg)

First thing would be to set `flex-column` in your card-img-overlay.

On last p I just set: `class="mx-auto"`

And if you want to set center, instead of `align-items-center` repoace that by `justify-content-center` (I did not do that)

I suggest you the below code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card" style="width: 70rem;margin-top:120px;margin-left:120px;">
    <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column">

        <div class="row">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="~/Graphics/homeiconservicepage.svg" style="width:25px;height:25px;" />
            <a href="@ViewBag.link">@ViewBag.text</a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="justify-content-center d-flex flex-column m-auto">
            <span class="mx-auto"> <text style="font-size:50px;"> @ViewBag.text </text></span>
            <p>
                We enable organizations from startups to large enterprises
                to make their work environment more efficient.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1552519507-da3b142c6e3d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" style="width:1200px;height:400px;" alt="Card image">
</div>
```

Comment: I am trying to make more center service text and below paregraph see this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/92PAY.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqziJ.png can you more help

Comment: You mean verticaly center?

Comment: see this image what I am trying to say https://i.stack.imgur.com/bl5VK.png

Comment: service text and paregraph text make it center means card top space and card bottom space is same and then service text and paregraph text make it center

Comment: Ok then set your « service text and below paregraph » to the same container div, add `flex-column` to the container. Please update the code in your question like this I could use it.

Comment: I hope you understood what I am trying to say

Comment: I did for sure, you want center horizontal and Vertical. Did you make these changes? Apply as well `m-auto` on your container

Comment: please see I update my question can you help more?

Comment: see my service text and paregraph is not center I want to center it means card top and card bottom space is same

Comment: Try updated code and you can check codepen too

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
  <p text style="color:black;margin-top:180px;padding-right:150px;padding-left:150px;text-align: center">
            We enable organizations from startups to large enterprises
            to make their work environment more efficient.
  </p>
```

Change the value of padding-right and padding-left according to your preference.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but not work https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhNPO.png

Answer (score 0):

Set style="text-align:center". It works for me.

```
<p style="text-align:center"> We enable organizations from startups to large enterprises to make their work environment more efficient.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

@niskuremdir, How about this does this work?

```
<span style="color:black;margin-top:180px;text-align:center">
<p>
We enable organizations from startups to large enterprises to make their work environment more efficient.
</p>
</span>
```

Try doing this with and without the `<p> </p>` and also try with both `<div> </div>` and `<span> </span>`
If that works, then you can go ahead and try to add the left/right padding:)

Answer (score 0):

You've to give width and height to parent container of text.

```
<div class="card" style="width: 70rem;margin-top:120px;margin-left:120px;">
  <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="row">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="~/Graphics/homeiconservicepage.svg" style="width:25px;height:25px;" />
      <a href="@ViewBag.link">@ViewBag.text</a>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center w-100 h-100">
       <div>
         <span> <text font-size:50px;"> @ViewBag.text </text></span>
       </div>
       <div>
          <p>
            We enable organizations from startups to large enterprises
                            to make their work environment more efficient.
          </p>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <img class="card-img-top" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1552519507-da3b142c6e3d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" style="width:1200px;height:400px;" alt="Card image">
</div>
```